# Viewmodel not cleared when using viewModelStore.clear()

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to clear out my view models after a flow through a couple of fragments has completed. When navigating from the last fragment in the flow to  the start screen, I call viewModelStore.clear() which as far as I understand, should clear out all view models. However, if I go through the flow again, data from the previous flow is persisted.

```
            actionButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewModelStore.clear()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_startScreenFragment)
        }
```

I tried to move the clear call into onDestroy and onDestroyView in my fragment as well, but nothing changes.

Am I misunderstanding something about clearing view models, or could someone maybe help me to understand the issue?

Comment: Have you checked that onCleared is called inside your view models?

Comment: @tomerpacific I just tried with the debugger to check if it was called. In the fragment, the viewModelStore.clear() method is called, but onCleared() in the viewmodel is not for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Could your viewmodel be bound to a specific flow?

Comment: The viewmodel is only references from two places, which is two fragments.
I navigate from start screen to fragment 1 where the viewmodel is used, the navigate from fragment 1 to fragment 2 where the viewmodel is also used. Then, when navigating from fragment 2 to start screen, I try to clear the view model, but with no success.